# What does "even in costume" mean here?

Tags: meaning, nouns

I was reading *The Invisible Man*, here's the sentence:

> The stranger did not go to church, and indeed made no difference between Sunday and the irreligious days, even in costume.

What does *even in costume* mean here? I don't quite get it, since both Sunday and irreligious days are *days*, unlike *costume* which is some sort of cloth.

[Original Chapter](http://www.bartleby.com/1003/4.html)

Comment: He wore the same kind of clothes on Sundays as on week days. People generally dress differently on Sundays (for the Church -- cf. 'Sunday best').

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means *even in the way he dressed.*  It implies he didn't dress up on Sundays, like his churchgoing counterparts did.

Comment: In times past, people used to dress up in their best clothes to go to church. It was considered a formal occasion. In the US, at least, this custom no longer really exists, people tend to wear the same clothes to church as they do to go to the store or whatever, making the reference possibly confusing to the modern reader.